# Order of operation for the Cross Product in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I realize that the order of operation for the Cross Product actually matters.
I understand that AxB = -BxA. (when A and B are vectors)

But I'm confused in finding the correct order. If you take a look at the picture I linked below, the exercise decided to label PQ vector U, and PR vector V. After that, they used the Cross Product with the following order: UxV.

So, is there a reason for assigning PQ vector U, and PR vector V? Why not the other way? Why can't PQ be V, and PR be U?

[image: the picture of my exercise]

Comment: Those are letters, and its order is arbitrary here. Note that the magnitude of a cross product is not affected by the order of its factors. The solution also carries a misprint: the norm bars are missing in the beginning of the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, a choice of sign does not matter, since the area of the triangle is given in terms of the *norm* of the cross product of two vectors. Remember that the norm of  a vector is equal to the norm of the negative of that vector.

Note the solution in the image is missing a bit: It should be

$$\frac 1 2 \|u \times v \|$$

at the first step, not just $\frac 1 2 u \times v$. A similar caveat applies to the right hand side of the first equality. (Notice the type error: the first line is about vectors, the second line is about numbers).

Comment: Makes sense. One more question if you don;t mind, why did the exercise pick PQ and PR in particular. Why not PQ and QR? Would it change the answer?

Comment: Try computing it and see that it won't change the answer.

Comment: Would someone mind explaining the downvote? If there's a correction, clarification, or improvement, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just get the negative if you do it that way, which gives the same answer for the area.